# Parsing apache log files

Tags: python, file-io

I just started learning Python and would like to read an Apache log file and put parts of each line into different lists.

line from the file

> 172.16.0.3 - - [25/Sep/2002:14:04:19 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 401 - "" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.1) Gecko/20020827"

according to [Apache website](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/logs.html) the format is

> %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\

I'm able to open the file and just read it as it is but I don't know how to make it read in that format so I can put each part in a list.

Comment: Which elements of this line are you interested in? (All of them?)

Comment: as the lines change slightly I would like them to be read in that exact format :)

Comment: You misunderstand- what I mean is, what do you want to extract from each line? The dates? IP? All of it?

Comment: you want to change the structure how the apache log file stores?

Comment: @DavidRobinson I'd like to put the ip in one list, the first "-" means nothing, the second "-" is the user so it should go into a user list, date and time into another list etc etc

Comment: @Surya
No, just be able to read each part of every line of an apache file

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This is a job for [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html).

For example:

```
line = '172.16.0.3 - - [25/Sep/2002:14:04:19 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 401 - "" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.1) Gecko/20020827"'
regex = '([(\d\.)]+) - - \[(.*?)\] "(.*?)" (\d+) - "(.*?)" "(.*?)"'

import re
print re.match(regex, line).groups()
```

The output would be a tuple with 6 pieces of information from the line (specifically, the groups within parentheses in that pattern):

```
('172.16.0.3', '25/Sep/2002:14:04:19 +0200', 'GET / HTTP/1.1', '401', '', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.1) Gecko/20020827')
```

Comment: This looks good but can I somehow have a "regex" for every part?
something like this
´ip = '([(\d\.)]+)'
 date = '.........'
 req =  '............'´

Comment: i think i figured it out.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: When I try some other line from the file it does not work.
ex

**127.0.0.1 - stefan [01/Apr/2002:12:17:21 +0200] "GET /sit3-shine.7.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 15811 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0(compatible; Konqueror/2.2.2-2; Linux)"**

Comment: @ogward: One reason it's not working is that the second dash isn't always a dash- in this case it's the name `stefan`. Replace it in the pattern with `(.*)`. (There will be other issues with lines in the file- I recommend you familiarize yourself with regex and I'm sure you'll be able to adapt my example.

Comment: Actually, it's not a job for regular expressions because any user supplied line in the request can contain a space or " that can throw off your parsing. For instance, if someone connects with a client that doesn't url escape space and ".  Who would do such a thing? Hackers!  It's easy to see how this breaks, just use telnet or netcat to connect to port 80 and make a manual request like
GET /dlkfj" lsakjdf HTTP/1.1

Answer (score 14):

I have created a python library which does just that: [apache-log-parser](https://github.com/rory/apache-log-parser).

```
>>> import apache_log_parser
 >>> line_parser = apache_log_parser.make_parser("%h <<%P>> %t %Dus \"%r\" %>s %b  \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %l %u")
>>> log_line_data = line_parser('127.0.0.1 <<6113>> [16/Aug/2013:15:45:34 +0000] 1966093us "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3478  "https://example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.2.18)" - -')
>>> pprint(log_line_data)
{'pid': '6113',
 'remote_host': '127.0.0.1',
 'remote_logname': '-',
 'remote_user': '',
 'request_first_line': 'GET / HTTP/1.1',
 'request_header_referer': 'https://example.com/',
 'request_header_user_agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.2.18)',
 'response_bytes_clf': '3478',
 'status': '200',
 'time_received': '[16/Aug/2013:15:45:34 +0000]',
 'time_us': '1966093'}
```

Answer (score 13):

Use a regular expression to split a row into separate "tokens":

```
>>> row = """172.16.0.3 - - [25/Sep/2002:14:04:19 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 401 - "" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.1) Gecko/20020827" """
>>> import re
>>> map(''.join, re.findall(r'\"(.*?)\"|\[(.*?)\]|(\S+)', row))
['172.16.0.3', '-', '-', '25/Sep/2002:14:04:19 +0200', 'GET / HTTP/1.1', '401', '-', '', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.1) Gecko/20020827']
```

Another solution is to use a dedicated tool, e.g. http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylogsparser/0.4

Answer (score 10):

RegEx seemed extreme and problematic considering the simplicity of the format, so I wrote this little splitter which others may find useful as well:

```
def apache2_logrow(s):
    ''' Fast split on Apache2 log lines

    http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/logs.html
    '''
    row = [ ]
    qe = qp = None # quote end character (qe) and quote parts (qp)
    for s in s.replace('\r','').replace('\n','').split(' '):
        if qp:
            qp.append(s)
        elif '' == s: # blanks
            row.append('')
        elif '"' == s[0]: # begin " quote "
            qp = [ s ]
            qe = '"'
        elif '[' == s[0]: # begin [ quote ]
            qp = [ s ]
            qe = ']'
        else:
            row.append(s)

        l = len(s)
        if l and qe == s[-1]: # end quote
            if l == 1 or s[-2] != '\\': # don't end on escaped quotes
                row.append(' '.join(qp)[1:-1].replace('\\'+qe, qe))
                qp = qe = None
    return row
```

Comment: This worked for me with Python 3. I was getting errors with the other regex examples. Thanks.

Comment: Used this to write a structured file with `header = ['host','identity','user','time','request','status','size','referer','user agent']` at the start.

Answer (score 6):

```
import re


HOST = r'^(?P<host>.*?)'
SPACE = r'\s'
IDENTITY = r'\S+'
USER = r'\S+'
TIME = r'(?P<time>\[.*?\])'
REQUEST = r'\"(?P<request>.*?)\"'
STATUS = r'(?P<status>\d{3})'
SIZE = r'(?P<size>\S+)'

REGEX = HOST+SPACE+IDENTITY+SPACE+USER+SPACE+TIME+SPACE+REQUEST+SPACE+STATUS+SPACE+SIZE+SPACE

def parser(log_line):
    match = re.search(REGEX,log_line)
    return ( (match.group('host'),
            match.group('time'), 
                      match.group('request') , 
                      match.group('status') ,
                      match.group('size')
                     )
                   )


logLine = """180.76.15.30 - - [24/Mar/2017:19:37:57 +0000] "GET /shop/page/32/?count=15&orderby=title&add_to_wishlist=4846 HTTP/1.1" 404 10202 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Baiduspider/2.0; +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"""
result = parser(logLine)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this in httpd.conf to convert the apache logs to json.

```
LogFormat "{\"time\":\"%t\", \"remoteIP\" :\"%a\", \"host\": \"%V\", \"request_id\": \"%L\", \"request\":\"%U\", \"query\" : \"%q\", \"method\":\"%m\", \"status\":\"%>s\", \"userAgent\":\"%{User-agent}i\", \"referer\":\"%{Referer}i\" }" json_log

CustomLog /var/log/apache_access_log json_log
CustomLog "|/usr/bin/python -u apacheLogHandler.py" json_log
```

Now you see you access_logs in json format.
Use the below python code to parse the json logs that are constantly getting updated.

apacheLogHandler.py

```
import time
f = open('apache_access_log.log', 'r')
for line in f: # read all lines already in the file
  print line.strip()

# keep waiting forever for more lines.
while True:
  line = f.readline() # just read more
  if line: # if you got something...
    print 'got data:', line.strip()
  time.sleep(1)
```