# how to get values in each column?

Tags: python

I have a text file with columns. I want to extract the data in column "C"

```
   A           B               C
  2013      colombo         sri lanka    
  2012      Tokyo           Japan
```

The flolowing is the code I used to find data.

```
f = open('log.txt','r')
data = f.read()
import re

#print data

def find(pat,text):
        match = re.search(pat,text)
        if match: print match.group()
        else: print 'not found!'

x = re.findall(r'\w+:',data)
print x
```

Comment: Do you have to use Python?  This is trivial with shell utilities.

Comment: yes i want to do this with python?

Comment: I'm confused... Where is the "find" function being used?  Also, could you be more specific about what belongs to columns A, B, and C?

Comment: We will need more information.  I see that it is possible for column C to have multiple words... Is it possible for column B to also have multiple words?  If so, the solution will not be easy.  If not it will be fairly straightforward.

Comment: can't you understand by the example?There are 3 columns,A B and C.And each column has values,I need to get the values in column C?

Comment: Did you look at [csv](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module?

Comment: What is that regex supposed to match? What it actually matches is one or more identifier characters, followed by a literal colon. Which means it will find nothing. If you left the colon off, it would find each word in every column (including the headers), which wouldn't do you any good. So… what were you _trying_ to do?

Comment: Ok, so here is the question that confuses everyone in this thread: what's the field separation in a row? Is that vertical alignment of a tab-separated file?

Comment: It appears that what you actually want to parse is not this format at all, but IIS web logs. Which you should have told us in the first place.

Comment: Assuming you're using one of the W3C/NCSA/Common [standard log formats](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/bea506fd-38bc-4850-a4fb-e3a0379d321f.mspx?mfr=true), this is exactly the same as parsing Apache logs, or any other server that uses those formats. Which means it's probably a dup of a dozen question on SO, like [Parsing apache log files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12544510/parsing-apache-log-files). I'd suggest doing a search, or going to PyPI to look around. I've heard good things about `pylogsparser` and `apachelog`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is underspecified, but I can try to make a guess at it. Given the "sri lanka" in column C, you can't just split on spaces. And if you've pasted it accurately, you're not using tabs.

So may, each column starts at a specific position in the line: column A is [3:12], column B is [12:28], column C is [28:]. In that case:

```
[line[29:] for line in data.splitlines()[1:]]
```

Another possibility is that you want to split on any run of *more than 1 space*, rather than just on spaces. In that case:

```
[filter(None, line.split('  '))[2] for line in data.splitlines()[1:]]
```

As it turns out, neither of those guesses is right, because your actual file format is… nothing like what you showed us, but rather one of the [standard IIS log formats](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/bea506fd-38bc-4850-a4fb-e3a0379d321f.mspx?mfr=true). You still haven't said which one, but assuming it's one of the W3C/NCSA/Common formats, this is exactly the same as parsing any web server log.

There are multiple Python modules made to do exactly this, including [`apachelog`](http://code.google.com/p/apachelog/) and [`pylogsparser`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylogsparser), but the best thing to do is probably to search for yourself and see what's out there.

Comment: Actually I wanted to get what ever under the "refer" field in an IIS server log file?Due to confidentiality I can not publish the content?E.g.                                                 #Fields: date time s-sitename s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status

Answer (score 1):

Your format is really underspecified - it's hard to get a good rule where one column ends and another starts. If you have some misaligned rows, it may be impossible to unambigously decide how the data corresponds to columns.

Hence, you're going to need some heuristics. A promising approach is to consider **columns delimited by at least 3 whitespace characters**:

```
>>> print data
   A           B               C
  2013      colombo         sri lanka
  2012      Tokyo           Japan

>>> re.compile('\s{3,}').split(line.strip()) for line in data.splitlines()]
[['A', 'B', 'C'],
 ['2013', 'colombo', 'sri lanka'],
 ['2012', 'Tokyo', 'Japan']]
```

The regular expression `\s{3,}` means "at least 3 whitespace characters".

Comment: Actually what i wanted was to read a IIS server log file and get what ever under the "refer" field?Due to confidentiality I can not publish the content?

Comment: Why did you pick delimited by at least 3 whitespace characters instead of just two?

Comment: @martineau No reason. :-) Just presenting the idea for a heuristic, the OP should tweak it to fit his actual input best

Comment: @NilaniAlgiriyage Really? I'm very surprised that software produces logs that aren't easily machine-readable

Comment: ok lets simplify this..:)I'm having an IIS server log file, as you know it has a field called cs(Referer)..I want to get all values under this column?please help me?

Comment: @NilaniAlgiriyage IIS appears to [offer several formats](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/bea506fd-38bc-4850-a4fb-e3a0379d321f.mspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('file.txt') as filehandler:
    for line in filehandler:
        print line.split(maxsplit=2)[2]
```

use `.split("\t")` if the fields are separated with tab

Additionally to *Kos* answer, you can split by regular expression. You can try splitting by words separated by at most one space:

```
with open('file.txt') as filehandler:
    for line in filehandler:
        groups = re.compile(r'((?:\w+\s?)+)').split(line)
        print groups[1], groups[3], groups[5]
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as Thai Tran's answer, and has the exact same problem.

Comment: maxsplit solves it. Also, if the file is separated with tab, then you use `.split("\t")` and you wont have that problem

Comment: `maxsplit` solves it for this particular case, but what about, say, "2009    Rio De Janeiro    Brazil"? As for `\t`—well, it's possible that he copied and pasted wrong, but otherwise, there are no tabs.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "correct your data". He seems to be trying to parse a log file. In order to correct that log file into something he can parse, he would need to parse it in the first place.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're telling me. I'm the one who told the OP that his problem was underspecified, 16 minutes before Kos did. And offered up two possible rules that seem like they might be what he's looking for (one of which is nearly identical to the one Kos guessed at), and explained why he has to give us the right rule if neither of my guesses is right.

Comment: aaa, i though you are OP. my fault, forgive me :) I delete that comment

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that column B will never be more than one word:

```
# This reads each line, removes the trailing newline, then splits on whitespace
data = [line.strip().split() for line in open('log.txt')]

# The columns
A = []
B = []
C = []
for line in data:
    A.append(line[0])
    B.append(line[1])
    # ' '.join(list) will return a string of the list separated by whitespace
    C.append(' '.join(line[2:]))

print C
```

`C` should contain only column C

Comment: It seems that the first row will be only `"lanka"`.

Comment: I doubt that's a good assumption, given that column B is clearly either capital cities or largest cities, and many of them have more than one word.

Comment: @bereal If sri is in element 2, and lanka is in element 3, line[2:] should return elements 2 and 3 so ' '.join(line[2:]) would contain both sri and lanka.

Comment: @SethMMorton: Why `split` everything and then `join` up [2:] in the first place when you can just pass `2` as the `maxsplit` parameter, much more simply?

Comment: @abarnert  I agree.  I asked the OP for clarification.  Unfortunately,  neither my answer nor the `maxsplit` option will work if B can also be multiple words.

Comment: @abarnert Indeed, `maxsplit` is more concise.

Comment: @SethMMorton: And I'm almost sure it _can_ be multiple words, which is why I gave two answers that can handle it rather than yet another copy of Thai Tran's (now-deleted) first answer.

Comment: ok lets simplify this..:)I'm having an IIS server log file, as you know it has a field called cs(Referer)..I want to get all values under this column?please help me?