# Spliting a sever access log string

Tags: python

i have been trying for some time now to split this server access log string, but to no avail.The string comes in this format

10.223.157.186 - - [15/Jul/2009:15:50:35 -0700] "GET /assets/css/reset.css HTTP/1.1" 200 1014

- %h is the IP address of the client
- %l is identity of the client, or "-" if it's unavailable
- %u is username of the client, or "-" if it's unavailable
- %t is the time that the server finished processing the request. The format is [day/month/year:hour:minute:second zone]
- %r is the request line from the client is given (in double quotes). It contains the method, path, query-string, and protocol or the request.
- %>s is the status code that the server sends back to the client. You will see see mostly status codes 200 (OK - The request has succeeded), 304 (Not Modified) and 404 (Not Found).
- %b is the size of the object returned to the client, in bytes. It will be "-" in case of status code 304

i have used `str.split() and str("\t") but to no avail. thanks for your help

Comment: might help to show the output you expect.

Comment: See [Parsing apache log files in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12544510/parsing-apache-log-files)

Comment: 10.223.157.186, -,  -, [15/Jul/2009:15:50:35 -0700], "GET /assets/css/reset.css HTTP/1.1",  200, 1014,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

For instance if you had this:

```
import re
line = '10.223.157.186 - - [15/Jul/2009:15:50:35 -0700] "GET /assets/css/reset.css HTTP/1.1" 200 1014'
regexString = r'(?P<IP>[0-9.]+) (?P<ID>[\w-]+) (?P<user>[\w-]+) (?P<time>\[.*\]) (?P<request>".*") (?P<status>\d+) (?P<size>\d+)'  
regex = re.compile(regexString)
match = regex.match(line)
if match != None:
    ip = match.group('IP')
    id = match.group('ID')
    # etc.
```

If you want to extract each thing from the time, i.e. the day, month, year, etc. then you can either run another regex on match.group('time') or you can be more explicit in the regexString about how to parse it.
For instance instead you could have: `\[(?P<day>\d+)/(?P<month>[A-Za-z]+)/(?P<year>\d+):(?P<hour>\d+):(?P<minute>\d+):(?P<second>\d+) -(?P<zone>\d+)\]`

This would get you:
`regexString = r'(?P<IP>[0-9.]+) (?P<ID>[\w-]+) (?P<user>[\w-]+) \[(?P<day>\d+)/(?P<month>[A-Za-z]+)/(?P<year>\d+):(?P<hour>\d+):(?P<minute>\d+):(?P<second>\d+) -(?P<zone>\d+)\] (?P<request>".*") (?P<status>\d+) (?P<size>\d+)'`

Comment: :) I hope this isn't too messy for you to understand. The `?P<name>` creates a named group that you can access with `match.group(name)` in the example I provided.

Comment: You're aware that now you have two problems, right? http://www.quickmeme.com/img/28/28267ccca83716ccddc3a2e194e8b0052cae3a204de3f37928a20e8ff4f0ee65.jpg

Comment: That meme only applies if don't know how to use a regex or if you get lost in it. The simple regex I provided is not difficult to understand. If you truly think this is a problem, feel free to add an answer

Comment: No, the solution is perfect, I even voted it up. It was just a joke, I didn't men to offend.