# parse log file delimited by space

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to parse apache access.log files in VB delimited by space, however one of the fields is enclosed by ""
I have tried

```
Using ioReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(foundFile)
ioReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
ioReader.SetDelimiters(" ")    ioReader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = True
Dim currentRow As String()
While Not ioReader.EndOfData
End While
End Using
```

However I receive the error: Line 1 cannot be parsed using the current Delimiters.
If I change HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = False, then my data is malformed

an example line i want to read is:

```
192.168.0.1 - - [17/Nov/2014:03:34:29 +0000] "GET /bluebell.html HTTP/1.1 "200 13675 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)" "-"[RT:0.769] [C:1115486]
```

Comment: If you set `HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes` to `true` every field must be wrapped with `"`. Have a look at the first field which already has no quotes on the left side.

Comment: Hi Thanks. I have modified the question. I am pulling the file from the web server access.log so I can't change the format :\

Comment: I think you should use regex instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12544510/parsing-apache-log-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to handle this. One way is use Try/Catch to ignore or repair any lines with improper formats. Another way is to read each line as a string and parse it yourself in the program using regex or string manipulation.

Comment: Thank you. I have delimited by string and run a checked for the elements that are enclosed and concatenated them together in a loop