# How to use group in match method to extract data from Apache logs

Tags: regex, ruby, match, logfile

I'm trying to extract the IP addresses and URLs from an Apache log file using grouping match.

The access.log file is:

```
10.0.0.3 - - [08/Jul/2019:10:26:41 +0000] "GET /hello.html HTTP/1.1" 404 444 "-" "curl/7.52.1"
10.0.0.3 - - [08/Jul/2019:10:26:41 +0000] "GET /hello.html HTTP/1.1" 404 444 "-" "curl/7.52.1"
10.0.0.3 - - [08/Jul/2019:10:26:41 +0000] "GET /secret.html HTTP/1.1" 200 282 "-" "curl/7.52.1"
```

And I'm using:

```
File.open("access.log").each do |line|
m = /(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})(.+\/)([a-zA-Z0-9]+.html)/.match(line)
puts m
end
```

`puts m` gives me this:

```
10.0.0.3 - - [08/Jul/2019:10:26:41 +0000] "GET /hello.html
```

`puts m[1]` and `puts m[3]` gives me an error:

```
1.rb:25:in block in <main>': undefined method []' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

I expected `"10.0.0.3"` and `"hello.html"`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Apache logs are well defined. There are pre-written patterns you can find and plug in that will split the line into fields so you can pick and choose the fields you want. That'd be a lot easier than rolling your own.

Comment: See https://github.com/weppos/apachelogregex. Also https://stackoverflow.com/a/30957416/128421 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/12544510/128421 might help.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error.

Answer (score 0):

Your expression seems to be working just fine, maybe we'd just a bit modify that to:

```
re = /(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})(.+\/)([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.html)/s
str = '10.0.0.3 - - [08/Jul/2019:10:26:41 +0000] "GET /hello.html HTTP/1.1" 404 444 "-" "curl/7.52.1"
10.0.0.3 - - [08/Jul/2019:10:26:41 +0000] "GET /hello.html HTTP/1.1" 404 444 "-" "curl/7.52.1"
10.0.0.3 - - [08/Jul/2019:10:26:41 +0000] "GET /secret.html HTTP/1.1" 200 282 "-" "curl/7.52.1"'

str.scan(re) do |match|
    puts match.to_s
end
```

#### Output

```
["10.0.0.3", " - - [08/Jul/2019:10:26:41 +0000] \"GET /", "hello.html"]
["10.0.0.3", " - - [08/Jul/2019:10:26:41 +0000] \"GET /", "hello.html"]
["10.0.0.3", " - - [08/Jul/2019:10:26:41 +0000] \"GET /", "secret.html"]
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/2dg7x2/1/) if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how general it can be, but try:

```
File.open("apache.log").each do |line|
  ip = line.split.first
  path = line.split(/(?:GET|POST|PUT|PATCH) /).last.split(/ (?:HTTP|HTTPS)/).first
  puts ("#{ip} - #{path}")
end
```

For the data sample it returns:

```
# 10.0.0.3 - /hello.html
# 10.0.0.3 - /hello.html
# 10.0.0.3 - /secret.html
```