# How to extract data from a web server log file, and also parse the request line portion?

Tags: python, text-files

Examples of the lines that I am trying to extract information from is given below.

```
[02/Jan/2015:08:07:32] "GET /click?article_id=162&user_id=5475 HTTP/1.1" 200 4352
[02/Jan/2015:08:08:43] "GET /click?article_id=139&user_id=19550 HTTP/1.1" 200 3078
[02/Jan/2015:08:09:01] "GET /click?article_id=87&user_id=9408 HTTP/1.1" 200 2005
[02/Jan/2015:08:09:18] "GET /click?article_id=175&user_id=9408 HTTP/1.1" 200 3467
```

I tried couple of approaches. One of them was

```
with open('C:/Users/.../access_log/access.log', 'r') as read:      
   for line in read:
      if "click?" in line:
          article_id = line.split('article_id=')[1]
          user_id = line.split('user_id=')[1]
          article.write(article_id)
          user.write(user_id)
```

I need to extract the `date`, `article_id`, `author_id` and the last two groups of digits. By using the code above my output looks like this

For user_id file the output looks like

```
  5475 HTTP/1.1" 200 4352
```

Here 5475 is the id that I need but the rest of the line comes with it. Similarly for `article_id` file the output is like

```
   162&user_id=5475 HTTP/1.1" 200 4352
```

Here 162 is the value I need but again I get the rest of the line with that value.

The second approach that I tried was this

```
for line in read:
   article_id = re.match('.*article_id=(\d+)', line)
   user_id = re.match('.*user_id=(\d+)', line)
   if article_id and article_id.lastindex > 0:
       ids.write(article_id.group(1))
```

But then I get an output like this

```
  1621398717554254614225905016411314518885592112332
```

I can't do this in excel because there are too many data points for excel to handle and all the file does not load properly. Also I need to make sure that when I extract the data points (`date`, `article_id`, `author_id`, ....) from each line, every data point corresponds to the other data point of the same line, so that I can see if there are missing values.

In essence is there a way that I could turn this

```
[02/Jan/2015:08:07:32] "GET /click?article_id=162&user_id=5475 HTTP/1.1" 200 4352
[02/Jan/2015:08:08:43] "GET /click?article_id=139&user_id=19550 HTTP/1.1" 200 3078
[02/Jan/2015:08:09:01] "GET /click?article_id=87&user_id=9408 HTTP/1.1" 200 2005
[02/Jan/2015:08:09:18] "GET /click?article_id=175&user_id=9408 HTTP/1.1" 200 3467
```

Into this

```
      Date                   Article_id    user_id       Response_code  Content size

      02/Jan/2015:08:07:32   162           5475          200            4352                     
      02/Jan/2015:08:08:43   139           19950         200            3078
```

Comment: I've had some success printing out tables to the console (or files) using https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec, which allows you to pad left/right, justify, and ensure that all data is legible when printed to a file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12544510/parsing-apache-log-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import re

parse_re = r'\[([^\[\]]*)\]\s+.*?article_id=(\d+).*?user_id=(\d+)[^\"]*?\"\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)'

with open('apache.log', 'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

for line in data:
    m = re.match(parse_re, line)
    if m:
        (date, article_id, user_id, response_code, content_size) =m.groups()
        print(date, article_id, user_id, response_code, content_size)
```

Output:

```
02/Jan/2015:08:07:32 162 5475 200 4352
02/Jan/2015:08:08:43 139 19550 200 3078
02/Jan/2015:08:09:01 87 9408 200 2005
02/Jan/2015:08:09:18 175 9408 200 3467
```

Comment: This doesn't handle missing values for `article_id` nor `user_id`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this simple regex to split your lines:

```
re.split(r' ".*?=|&.*?=| .*?" ', line)
```

Output:

```
['[02/Jan/2015:08:07:32]', '162', '5475', '200 4352']
```

You can also use `findall`:

```
re.findall(r'\[(.*?)\].*?(\d+).*?(\d+).*?(\d+)\s(\d+)', line)
```

Output:

```
[('02/Jan/2015:08:07:32', '162', '5475', '200', '4352')]
```

You can assign that `re.findall` to variable and use simple accessing to the elements, for example:

```
data = re.findall(r'\[(.*?)\].*?(\d+).*?(\d+).*?(\d+)\s(\d+)', line)
print data[0][0]
02/Jan/2015:08:07:32
```

**Note:** If any value is missing you'll see it, but mine solutions won't show you which one is missing in particular.

Comment: OP wanted to have 'response_code' and 'content_size' parsed separately and 'date' should not contain '[]'

Comment: @MaxU ok, thanks for down voting, i added some findall to return what op needs

Comment: And i returned a favor:)

Comment: @EthanFurman, why do you downvote my answer if it solves the op's problem? There is no such requirement from OP to do what you just said.

Comment: there is no way to say which one is missing by using just findall, i don't want to wrap it in additional logic and do all the work for the OP, but you keep downvoting, you are great at it.

Comment: i just don't see a reason for downvote in this particular answer.

Comment: ok here is what he asks - "every data point corresponds to the other data point of the same line, so that I can see if there are missing values". So my answer will show that values are missing, which one is missing is another quest which OP doesn't ask.

Comment: I added the note you wanted to see:)

Answer (score 0):

@Amit : I have the below code with re

```
import re
a='[02/Jan/2015:08:07:32] "GET /click?article_id=162&user_id=5475 HTTP/1.1" 200 4352 '

for line in a:
    match =  re.search("\[(\d+\/[A-Za-z]+\/\d+\:\d+\:\d+\:\d+)\] \"GET\/click\article_id\=(\d+)\&user_id\=(\d+) HTTP\/1\.1\" (\d+) (\d+)",line)
    if match: 
         print "%s   %s  %s %s %s  " %( match.group(1), match.group(2), match.group(3), match.group(4), match.group(5) )

output 
02/Jan/2015:08:07:32   162  5475 200 4352
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to parse the `GET` segment, and be able to tell when pieces are missing, a small function will do the job:

```
def extract_get_fields(line):
    # fields should be a list desired field names
    if 'GET' not in line:
        return None
    result = {}
    line = line.split('GET ', 1)[1]
    line = line.rsplit('"', 1)[0]
    line = line.rsplit(None, 1)[0]
    # line is now the segment between GET and the last double quote
    result['page'], crumbs = line.split('?')
    for crumb in crumbs.split('&'):
        name, value = crumb.split('=')
        result[name] = value
    return result
```

and in use:

```
# second and third lines are missing pieces
data = [
    '[02/Jan/2015:08:07:32] "GET /click?article_id=162&user_id=5475 HTTP/1.1" 200 4352',
    '[02/Jan/2015:08:08:43] "GET /click?article_id=139 HTTP/1.1" 200 3078',
    '[02/Jan/2015:08:09:01] "GET /click?user_id=9408 HTTP/1.1" 200 2005',
    '[02/Jan/2015:08:09:18] "GET /click?article_id=175&user_id=9408 HTTP/1.1" 200 3467',
    ]

for line in data:
    result = extract_get_fields(line)
    if result is None:
        # wasn't a GET line, skip it
        continue
    if result['page'] != '/click':
        # wasn't a click page, skip it
        continue
    article_id = result.get('article_id', '')
    user_id = result.get('user_id', '')
    print('article_id: %5s   user_id: %s' % (article_id, user_id))
```

which results in:

```
article_id:   162   user_id: 5475
article_id:   139   user_id: 
article_id:         user_id: 9408
article_id:   175   user_id: 9408
```

---

Note:  You'll need to enhance and/or combine with the other answers to alse get the `date` and other fields.