# How to split a RDD into spaces by ignoring spaces within double quotation marks and square brackets

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I need to analyse a txt document with thousands of rows, but I'm having trouble splitting the data into spaces because there are spaces enclosed in double quotation marks and square brackets that should not be considered. How could I do this?

I am using this code:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
lines = sc.textFile('C:\\test.txt')
parts = lines.map(lambda line: line.replace(' - - ', ' ').split(' '))
print(parts.glom().collect())
```

The first row is:

> 199.72.81.55 - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:01 -0400] "GET /history/apollo/ HTTP/1.0" 200 6245

And the output is:

> ['199.72.81.55', '[01/Jul/1995:00:00:01', '-0400]', '"GET',
>   '/history/apollo/', 'HTTP/1.0"', '200', '6245']

But should be:

> ['199.72.81.55', '[01/Jul/1995:00:00:01 -0400]', '"GET
>   /history/apollo/ HTTP/1.0"', '200', '6245']

I'm starting to learn Spark and I'm kind of lost. I've tried everything and I can not solve this problem.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you considered using regular expressions? thousands of log lines isn't  big deal for pyspark to handle. Regular expressions are slower as compared to a simple `split` but can help you separate them properly.

Comment: @nightgaunt, I have no problem about regex, but I do not know how to apply it here. I saw in another post this regular expression **(- - | (? <=)) | (? <= \\ ") | (? <= \\ d) (? = \\ d))** that might help me with this problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using regular expressions can help you with splitting the log record properly. Also, it will allow for customizing the RDD as per your need.

A sample regex which I shamelessly copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/12544587/10378736

```
regex = r'([(\d\.)]+) - - \[(.*?)\] "(.*?)" (\d+) (\d+)'
```

- The first group `([(\d\.)]+)` separates your IP address
- `- -` are ignored as they are not enclosed by `()`
- `\[(.*?)\]` groups everything inside the `[]`
- `"(.*?)"` groups everything inside quotes
- `(\d+)` gives you the response status
- Last `(\d+)` gives you the response time

Be warned: This regex does not cover all cases of your apache log format. This Regex can break for thousands of cases which are quite normal/usual apache log. But for the scope of answer, I will just use a sample regex. It is upto you to explore more.

Regarding implementation, you are already using `map` to iterate over each line.

```
parts = lines.map(lambda line: re.match(regex, line).groups())
```

My unsolicited advice is to decide on the aggregate part first and then split the log line accordingly. This will save a lot of execution time during aggregation and producing the final result.

Comment: Thanks nightgaunt. I am trying to test this but the code I was using to show the result `print(parts.glom().collect())` doesn't work with regex (I don't know why). Could you help me?

Comment: Maybe you didn't `import re`?

Comment: Now I understand the problem. How do you said, this regex does'n cover all cases and in the txt I have situations where the host is the internet address (_midcom.com_) instead of IP (_199.72.81.55_). These rows are causing a problem in printing (the error is giant but I think that is something about null value). I'm gonna try to change this regex for covering all situations. Thank you! (I can't give you +1 because of my poor reputation).

Comment: @nightgaunt can you help me for same in scala as well

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Working for me.

Input file value :

```
199.72.81.55 - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:01 -0400] "GET /history/apollo/ HTTP/1.0" 200 6245
```

Code :

```
trdd=sc.textFile('file')
import re
o = trdd.flatMap(lambda x : ((v) for v in re.split('([(\d\.)]+) - - \[(.*?)\] "(.*?)" (\d+) (\d+)',x)))
```

Output :

```
>>> for i in o.collect():    print(i)                             ...

199.72.81.55
01/Jul/1995:00:00:01 -0400
GET /history/apollo/ HTTP/1.0
200
6245
```

Comment: Thank you, Mayur! You code helped me a lot. This solution don't cause the error that I was having with nightgaunt's code but I still have problems due to variations in the txt pattern (no split when I have the internet addres instead of IP). I am gonna think how to improve the regex. (I can't give you +1 because of my poor reputation)