# Ignoring quotation marks on re

Tags: python, python-re

I was trying to convert my data into a list of dictionaries like

```
example_dict = {"host":"146.204.224.152", 
                "user_name":"feest6811", 
                "time":"21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700",
                "request":"POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1"} #note: not everything is a POST
```

My data:

```
146.204.224.152 - feest6811 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700] "POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1" 302 4622
197.109.77.178 - kertzmann3129 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:25 -0700] "DELETE /virtual/solutions/target/web+services HTTP/2.0" 203 26554
156.127.178.177 - okuneva5222 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:27 -0700] "DELETE /interactive/transparent/niches/revolutionize HTTP/1.1" 416 14701
100.32.205.59 - ortiz8891 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:28 -0700] "PATCH /architectures HTTP/1.0" 204 6048
168.95.156.240 - stark2413 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:31 -0700] "GET /engage HTTP/2.0" 201 9645
71.172.239.195 - dooley1853 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:32 -0700] "PUT /cutting-edge HTTP/2.0" 406 24498
180.95.121.94 - mohr6893 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:34 -0700] "PATCH /extensible/reinvent HTTP/1.1" 201 27330
144.23.247.108 - auer7552 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:35 -0700] "POST /extensible/infrastructures/one-to-one/enterprise HTTP/1.1" 100 22921
```

My code:

```
pattern = """
(?P<host>.*)     #User host
(-\ )            #Separator
(?P<user_name>\w*) #User name
(\ \[)             #Separator for pharanteses and space
(?P<time>\S*\ -0700) #time
(\]\ )             #Separator for pharanteses and space
(?P<request>\w* ")
"""
for user in re.finditer(pattern,logdata,re.VERBOSE):
    print(user.groupdict())
```

Output: [image]

I couldn't get rid of the quotation mark. Tried to add **\"** or just **"** to seperator line but then I couldn't get any output.

Comment: Why would you use a regex for matching structured data?

Comment: ...specifically, as Python literals, this is best parsed using `ast.literal_eval()`. Trying to roll your own parser is a path to madness (or at least, subtle bugs that only get detected months later when unusual data gets generated, after you're on to new projects and don't remember the details of how the hand-rolled parser was built).

Comment: Wait, not Python literals, mixed up what's input and output. Don't provide input as screenshots, provide it as text. Otherwise nobody can test their answers. See [Why not upload images of code/data when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122)

Comment: ...for log parsing _specifically_, there are 3rd-party libraries that do it for you out-of-the-box. So while `ast.literal_eval` was the wrong answer, "don't roll your own" still holds.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/apachelogs/; or, for something simpler, https://stackoverflow.com/a/29376301/14122

Comment: Solving by using re was requested. Have edited my input, sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Requested, yes, but our scope is _practical_, answerable questions. Deliberately choosing the wrong tool for the job is, well, _impractical_.

Comment: That said, to be less snarky and more helpful, a lookahead assertion might be what you want. Or you can just move the `)` to be _before_ the `"` (though you'll need to reformulate the regex for other reasons as well, as described below)

Comment: Right now your regex stops at the _opening_ quote instead of the _closing_ one. Matching that opening quote explicitly, so the pattern looks for the closing quote only after the opening one is seen, is a way to solve that.

Comment: `"(?P<request>(?:\w\s*)*)"` is one very untested, very off the top of my head suggestion. For a _tested_ regex, the existing answers to the linked duplicate are the place to start.