# How to parse Apache Log File, Swiftly?

Tags: swift, regex, parsing

Suppose I have a log file that I've split into an array of strings. For example I have these lines here.

> 123.4.5.1 - - [03/Sep/2013:18:38:48 -0600] "GET /products/car/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3327 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.65 Safari/537.36"

> 123.4.5.6 - - [03/Sep/2013:18:38:58 -0600] "GET /jobs/ HTTP/1.1" 500 821 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0"

I can parse these out with typical string manipulation however I think there is a better way to do it with Regex. I attempted to follow a similar pattern that someone had used in [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12544510/parsing-apache-log-files), but I can't quite figure it out. Here's my attempt.

This is the pattern: ([(\d.)]+) - - [(.*?)] "(.*?)" (\d+) - "(.*?)" "(.*?)" when I attempt to use it, I get no matches.

```
let lines = contents.split(separator: "\n")
            let pattern = "([(\\d\\.)]+) - - \\[(.*?)\\] \"(.*?)\" (\\d+) - \"(.*?)\" \"(.*?)\""
            let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [])
            for line in lines {
                let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: line.utf16.count)
                let parsedData = regex.firstMatch(in: String(line), options: [], range: range)
                print(parsedData)
            }
```

If I could extract the data to a model that would be the best. I need to ensure that the code is performant and fast because there could be thousands of lines I should account for.

#### Expected Result

```
let someResult = (String, String, String, String, String, String) or 
let someObject: LogFile = LogFile(String, String, String...)
```

I would be looking for the parsed line to be broken up into it's individual parts. `IP`, `OS`, `OS Version`, `Browser` `Browser Version` etc.. any real parsing of the data will be sufficient.

Comment: That looks more like an Apache log file to me.

Comment: @MartinR yes it is, that was a typo on my part. It's corrected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With your shown samples, could you please try following.

```
^((?:\d+\.){3}\d+).*?\[([^]]*)\].*?"([^"]*)"\s*(\d+)\s*(\d+)\s*"-"\s*"([^"]*)"$
```

[Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/NRY4L3/1)

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
^(                   ##Starting a capturing group checking from starting of value here.
   (?:\d+\.){3}\d+   ##In a non-capturing group matching 3 digits followed by . with 1 or more digits
)                    ##Closing 1st capturing group here.
.*?\[                ##Matching non greedy till [ here.
([^]]*)              ##Creating 2nd capturing group till ] here.
\].*?"               ##Matching ] and non greedy till " here.
([^"]*)              ##Creating 3rd capturing group which has values till " here.
"\s*                 ##Matching " spaces one or more occurrences here.
(\d+)                ##Creating 4th capturing group here which has all digits here.
\s*                  ##Matching spaces one or more occurrences here.
(\d+)                ##Creating 5th capturing group here which has all digits here.
\s*"-"\s*"           ##Spaces 1 or more occurrences "-" followed by spaces  1 or more occurrences " here.
([^"]*)              ##Creating 6th capturing group till " here.
"$                   ##Matching " at last.
```

Comment: You're clearly a regex god. This solution worked.

Answer (score 2):

The correct regex pattern is the one provided by @RavinderSingh13 however I also want to add what I did to make it function properly within my code so that others can use it in the future without having to search all of StackOverflow for answers.

I needed to find a way to parse an Apache Log File into a usable object within swift. The code is as follows.

#### Implement Extension

```
extension String {
    func groups(for regexPattern: String) -> [[String]] {
        do {
            let text = self
            let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regexPattern)
            let matches = regex.matches(in: text,
                                        range: NSRange(text.startIndex..., in: text))
            return matches.map { match in
                return (0..<match.numberOfRanges).map {
                    let rangeBounds = match.range(at: $0)
                    guard let range = Range(rangeBounds, in: text) else {
                        return ""
                    }
                    return String(text[range])
                }
            }
        } catch let error {
            print("invalid regex: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return []
        }
    }
}
```

#### Create Model Object

```
class EventLog {
    let ipAddress: String
    let date: String
    let getMethod: String
    let statusCode: String
    let secondStatusCode: String
    let versionInfo: String
    
    init(ipAddress: String, date: String, getMethod: String, statusCode: String, secondStatusCode: String, versionInfo: String ){
        self.ipAddress = ipAddress
        self.date = date
        self.getMethod = getMethod
        self.statusCode = statusCode
        self.secondStatusCode = secondStatusCode
        self.versionInfo = versionInfo
    }
}
```

#### Parse The Data

I want to point out that the regex pattern returns an [[String]] so you MUST get the subGroup from the returned overarching group. Similar to parsing JSON.

```
func parseData() {
        let documentsUrl:URL =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        let destinationFileUrl = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent("logfile.log")
        
        do {
            let contents = try String(contentsOf: destinationFileUrl, encoding: .utf8)
            let lines = contents.split(separator: "\n")
            let pattern = "^((?:\\d+\\.){3,}\\d).*?\\[([^]]*)\\].*?\"([^\"]*)\"\\s*(\\d+)\\s+(\\d+)\\s*\"-\"\\s*\"([^\"]*)\"$"
            for line in lines {
                let group = String(line).groups(for: pattern)
                let subGroup = group[0]
                let ipAddress = subGroup[1]
                let date = subGroup[2]
                let getMethod = subGroup[3]
                let statusCode = subGroup[4]
                let secondStatusCode = subGroup[5]
                let versionInfo = subGroup[6]
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.eventLogs.append(EventLog(ipAddress: ipAddress, date: date, getMethod: getMethod, statusCode: statusCode, secondStatusCode: secondStatusCode, versionInfo: versionInfo))
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The pattern has no matches because at the place of the hyphen, there are 1+ digits.

To make the pattern a bit more performant, you can use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `"([^"]*)"`  to capture for example any char except `"` between `"`

```
(\d+(?:\.\d+)+) - - \[([^\]\[]+)\] "([^"]*)" (\d+) (\d+) "[^"]+" "([^"]+)"
```

- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)+)` Capture group 1, match 1+ digits and repeat 1+ times a `.` and 1+ digits
- `- -` Match literally
- `\[([^\]\[]+)\]`  Match `[` capture 1+ times any char except `[` and `]` in group 2 and match the `]`
- `"([^"]*)"`   Match `"` capture 1+ times any char except `"` in group 3 and match the `"`
- `(\d+) (\d+)`  Capture group 4 and 5 matching 1+ digits
- `"[^"]+"`  Same as previous mechanism for `"` but match only
- `"([^"]+)"` Same as previous mechanism for `"` in group 6

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uE8vab/1) | [Swift demo](https://rextester.com/GRQL74324)

Example code

```
let pattern = #"(\d+(?:\.\d+)+) - - \[([^\]\[]+)\] "([^"]*)" (\d+) (\d+) "[^"]+" "([^"]+)""#
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: .anchorsMatchLines)
let testString = #"123.4.5.1 - - [03/Sep/2013:18:38:48 -0600] "GET /products/car/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3327 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.65 Safari/537.36""#
let stringRange = NSRange(location: 0, length: testString.utf16.count)
let matches = regex.matches(in: testString, range: stringRange)
var result: [[String]] = []
for match in matches {
    var groups: [String] = []
    for rangeIndex in 1 ..< match.numberOfRanges {
        groups.append((testString as NSString).substring(with: match.range(at: rangeIndex)))
    }
    if !groups.isEmpty {
        result.append(groups)
    }
}
print(result)
```

Output

```
[["123.4.5.1", "03/Sep/2013:18:38:48 -0600", "GET /products/car/ HTTP/1.1", "200", "3327", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.65 Safari/537.36"]]
```

Comment: I'm not sure why I can't get this pattern to work. I get an invalid Regex error thrown whenever I attempt to use it.

Comment: @xTwisteDx I see it, you have to escape the square brackets in the character class `\[([^\]\[]+)\]` I have updated the answer.