# Convert access.log file into json file using python

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch

I'm trying to convert access.log file of nginx into json format but i'm facing following error

> Index error: list index out of range

```py
import json

i = 1
result = {}
with open('access.log') as f:
lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    r = str.split('\\s+')
    result[i-1] = {'timestamp': r[0], 'monitorip': r[1], 'monitorhost': r[2], 'monitorstatus': 
    r[3], 'monitorid': r[4], 'resolveip': r[5]}
    i += 1 
    print(result) 
with open('data.json', 'w') as fp:
json.dump(result, fp)
```

Below is the log format I'm trying to convert

[image: Below is the log format I'm trying to convert]

Error i face is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/test.py", line 10, in <module>

result[i-1] = {'timestamp': r[0], 'monitorip': r[1], 'monitorhost': 
r[2], 'monitorstatus': r[3], 'monitorid': r[4], 'resolveip': r[5]}

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: The argument to `str.split()` isn't a regular expression, it's a plain string. Leaving out the argument defaults to splitting on any whitespace, which is what you want.

Comment: Also, `str.split()` should be `line.split()`.

Comment: Did you spend any time debugging this? If you simply did `print(r)` you would have seen the problem.

Comment: And your indentation is wrong, but I'm guessing that's a copying error when you posted here.

Comment: Don't post images, just paste the text into the question in a code block.

Comment: Use [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+parse+access+log+answers%3A1) to find lots of previous questions about parsing access.log in python.

Comment: it's a parsing issue, not related to ES itself. This should help: https://gist.github.com/hreeder/f1ffe1408d296ce0591d

Comment: @Barmar i have updated the error in the main question when i run the code, kindly look at that

Comment: What does `print(r)` show when the error happens?

Answer (score 0):

Use `line.split()` instead of `str.split('\\s+')`. `split()` takes a regular string as the delimiter, not a regular expression. And it defaults to using any whitespace as the delimiter.

Check that `r` has enough fields before trying to use it. This will skip any incomplete lines.

```
import json

i = 0
result = {}

with open('access.log') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

for line in lines:
    r = line.split()
    if len(r) >= 6:
        result[i] = {'timestamp': r[0], 'monitorip': r[1], 'monitorhost': r[2], 'monitorstatus': 
                     r[3], 'monitorid': r[4], 'resolveip': r[5]}
        i += 1
    print(result) 

with open('data.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(result, fp)
```

Comment: I want to use this regular expression instead of 'line.split()'

re.compile(r"\\b(?:(?:2(?:[0-4][0-9]|5[0-5])|[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9])\\.){3}(?:(?:2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5])|[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9]))\\b - - \\[[^\\]]*] \"(?:[^\\\\\"]|\\\\\\\\|\\\\\")*\"[^\"]*\"-\" \"(?:[^\\\\\"]|\\\\\\\\|\\\\\")*\"", re.IGNORECASE)

Comment: Feel free to do so.

Comment: may you please help me? I'm facing issue in it. May you modify the code

Comment: Try the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12544510/parsing-apache-log-files)